# jQuery show content on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

Basically have a table of products, something similar to:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product 1 <br> Brief info</td>
    <td>Product 2 <br> Brief info</td>
    <td>Product 3 <br> Brief info</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When a user hovers over a table cell I would like to slightly fade out the cell and then have some content overlay that cell with a call to action to the product page.

Not been too succesful with getting this to work so any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of : [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("table td").hover(
 function () {
     // mouse over
  }, 
  function () {
   // mouse out
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ntu2z/1/)**